# Protection From Browser Dev Tools Changing POST Values

Tags: javascript, html, django

After looking around for a bit, I cannot seem to find an answer to my question... Or maybe I am just not wording my question correctly in my search.

**Any-who, my question and description is as follows:**

I am building a web application using Django, Javascript, HTML, and all that Jazz. I am currently testing my checkout page and noticed a security issue I do not know how to handle.

**Issue:**

I can open up developer tools and change the 'value' of whatever I want on my HTML and that is the value that ultimately gets passed back in the POST request.

How do I make it so that changing the HTML values using dev tools on the browser doesn't effect the values being sent back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, all input from a browser must be validated serverside

Comment: How would you suggest doing this? Instead of just grabbing the value, grab the ID of the item and if it is not what it is supposed to be, throw an error? If this is the case, what if someone changes the ID to the ID of something cheaper.. Should I test more than just the ID?

Comment: Can you list all the values there are being posted?

Comment: They are dollar values to determine the final cost to be charged to a customer. These values come from select menu drop downs, radio buttons, and checkboxes. Each item has their own unique ID.

Comment: You should post quantity and item id, then validate the quantity (must be a positive int), get the product item from the database (throw error if not found), and multiply quantity and price

Comment: I don't feel quantity is necessary as there is only a single choice able to be made for each option. Are you saying I should store the product ID and cost in my database rather than just have those values in my utility function (backend)?

Comment: If quantity always are 1, then just retrieve the price from your preferred ways to store your products (the backend function in your case)

Comment: Appreciate the insight... Do you feel it would be more efficient or see some benefit from me just storing the item names and values in my DB?

Comment: It is more flexible to store it in a database (you can create/update/delete items programmatically), ex. for a admin panel in long term, but be aware of sql injection, if you a going to store it in a database, then you must give each item a id, and use the id for referring to the item

Comment: Your responses have been very helpful.. thank you for your time and help!